# Zoom to selected record from Fusion Table in google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to zoom to a selected record from a fusion table using Lat and Long values and using google maps API. This works OK if I run it locally on my computer but not after I deploy it to a website. Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
//query FT data for visualization
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'table', 'geomap']});
    var FTresponse = null;

    function  createSidebar() {

    var queryText = encodeURIComponent("SELECT 'poly_id', 'crop2017', 'lat', 'long', 'latlng' FROM 1Vz_znG-dqaFrWRY-4irnnIxQkSRMVzbrpe7Lb_v4");
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

    query.send(getData);

    }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(createSidebar); 

  //write FT data to table

  function getData(response) {
                if (!response) {
                alert('no response');
                 return;
                }
                    if (response.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
                    }
                 FTresponse = response;
            loadSidebarText(response, "ALL");

            table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('visualization_div'));
            datatable = response.getDataTable();
            table.draw(datatable, {showRowNumber: true});

            add table listener when row clicked
            google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', myFTclick);
        }
        //end function

 //Load data to sidebar       

  function loadSidebarText(response, crop2017) {
  var numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  var numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();

  var fusiontabledata = "<table><tr>";
    fusiontabledata += "<th>" + response.getDataTable().getColumnLabel(2) + "</th>";

  fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
    for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
          if (crop2017 === "ALL" || response.getDataTable().getValue(i,1) === crop2017) {
        fusiontabledata += "<td><a href='javascript:myFTclick("+i+")'>"+response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1) + "</a></td>";
            fusiontabledata += "</tr><tr>";
            }
  }

  fusiontabledata += "</table>";
  window.onload = document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML = fusiontabledata;
}      

    //match table data to map data
        function myFTclick(row) {
            //var poly_id = FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,2);
            //var crop2017= FTresponse.getDataTable ().getValue(row,4);
            var latlng =  FTresponse.getDataTable().getValue(row,4);
            var split = latlng.split(',');
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(split[0], split[1]);
                map.setCenter(position);
```

When I run it and select a record I get error messages saying Uncaught Error: Invalid row index [object Object]. Should be in the range [0-282] and Uncaught ReferenceError: myFTclick is not defined at :1:1.

Is anyone able to show me where I am going wrong please?

You can see my whole code so far at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02ytw0ht/4/)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have now added a fiddle which shows all of my code.

Comment: It isn't **minimal** (i.e. [mcve]), and it doesn't work (i.e. it doesn't exhibit the issue).